# Possible to tweet using appkey/secret key from a different account via twython?

Tags: twitter, twython

I have a twitter account with an App made, currently it's setup so students can tweet from our website and as such their tweets show "via SchoolAppNameHere" at the bottom of their tweets.

Is it possible to use Twython to use the Appkey and secret key and then get auth tokens from a completely different so when I was to run the bit of code below it would tweet from an account what didn't create the app...

```
from twython import Twython

APP_KEY = ''
APP_SECRET = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter.update_status(status="test")
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

## Edit, Updated example/explanation below:

Let's say the following image's are from the account "stackoverflowapp" and the app called "Stackoverflow Test App":

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8sIpak5.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/e6CYt6e.png]

Using the following bit of code would tweet from the account "stackoverflowapp" with the tweet "test" via the applicationg called "Stackoverflow Test App"

```
from twython import Twython

APP_KEY = 'coN_kEY_123456789'
APP_SECRET = 'cOn_sEcr3t_123456789'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'Acc3ss_tok3N_123456789'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'aCCeSS_tOkEn_sEcrET_123456789'

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter.update_status(status="test")
```

Let's say that the following image is from the account "useraccount1" and the app is called "testing123":

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vYJLmfr.png]

So now that I have the access tokens to login to the account "useraccount1", how can I tweet via the app called "Stackoverflow test app" which was created by the user: "stackoverflowapp" example of what I tried is below:

```
from twython import Twython

APP_KEY = 'coN_kEY_123456789'
APP_SECRET = 'cOn_sEcr3t_123456789'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'Acc3ss_123456789'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'aCCeSS_sEcrET_123456789'

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter.update_status(status="test update")
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
TwythonAuthError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Could not authenticate you
```

Comment: As long as the `OAUTH_TOKEN` and `OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET` have been authorized with your `APP_KEY` and `APP_SECRET` pair then you can tweet on behalf of that user. So what you can't do is use tokens that were authorized against a completely different application, i.e. tokens are non-interchangable between apps. Does this make sense? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @soulseekah I've updated my original post to show the problem in more detail, see my edit.

Comment: This is not how OAuth2 works. Your "useraccount1" tokens are only valid for "testing123" and cannot be used with "Stackoverflow Test App". You have to request "useraccount1"'s tokens explicitly. See: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-1.4 "Access tokens are credentials used to access protected resources. An access token is a string representing an authorization issued to the client."

Comment: So, each token is unique, and represents an agreement to authorize access to specific resources (a concrete user's twitter feed, in this case) to a specific consumer (your app, in this case). What exactly are you trying to solve? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @soulseekah Yes, I've gathered by trial and error that `useraccount1`'s tokens are only valid for the `testing123` app keys. it's not a case of XY problem because I'm not "stuck on one approach" if someone is able to help with snippits and/or point me in a better direction.

Comment: @soulseekah In my case, it's pretty clear that I'm trying to tweet using an app key from a different account... so that it appears with `via AppNameHere`

Comment: It's still unclear what you're stuck on. What stops you from requesting tokens for your other app and authorize the other app to tweet, too?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token

Comment: https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course, possible. When you create an application in Twitter, they give you your own authentication tokens for you to use immediately, as a convenience.

> Use the access token string as your "oauth_token" and the access token secret as your "oauth_token_secret" to sign requests with **your own Twitter account**. Do not share your oauth_token_secret with anyone.

To get keys for other accounts for the same application, you need to request more keys for each account. This is described in detail here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens

Since it sounds like you're going to be doing the authorization yourself, the simpler [PIN-based](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization) approach should probably be used.

You're using `twython`, obtaining these can be done using the library: https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#authentication

`get_authentication_tokens` and `get_authorized_tokens` are the methods you're looking for.

```
from twython import Twython
import sys

APP_KEY = 'coN_kEY_123456789'
APP_SECRET = 'cOn_sEcr3t_123456789'

twitter = Twython( APP_KEY, APP_SECRET )
auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()

print( 'Visit %s and enter your PIN: ' % auth.get( 'auth_url' ) ),
pin = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

twitter = Twython( APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, auth.get( 'oauth_token' ), auth.get( 'oauth_token_secret' ) )
tokens = twitter.get_authorized_tokens( pin )

print( 'OAUTH_TOKEN: %s' % tokens.get( 'oauth_token' ) )
print( 'OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET: %s' % tokens.get( 'oauth_token_secret' ) )
```

Store `OAUTH_TOKEN` and `OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET` some place safe and reuse at will. Also, make sure you authorize the correct account when visiting the URL and getting the PIN.

All your API calls will be made on bahalf the account that authorized access via the tokens and your `via` line will be your original application. Use the appropriate tokens for each account you'd like to tweet from, it's not possible to mix and match.